# Remove Trailing Slash Using PHP

Tags: magento-1.9, php, link

I'm trying to remove the trailing slash from this link:

```
href="<?php echo Mage::helper('supermenu')->getLinkbyItem($item); ?>"
```

In the module there is a field that one uses to enter the link used in the above.  I enter the link such as `christmas.html` but the link gets a trailing slash like this: `.../christmas.html/`

I found this [Remove Trailing Slash From String PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319105/remove-trailing-slash-from-string-php/4319119)
 using `rtrim`but don't know how to use it in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
echo rtrim(Mage::helper('supermenu')->getLinkbyItem($item), '/');
```

Comment: I tried it and it and it does seem to do anything.

Comment: Sorry @Freejoy ... missed something ... updated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you would simply wrap the entire part that is being echoed.  It would look like this:

```
href="<?php echo rtrim(Mage::helper('supermenu')->getLinkbyItem($item)); ?>"
```